# Minetest crashes when checking the "public server list" box

Tags: 14.04, games, troubleshooting

I think this has something to do with libjsoncpp. There is a patch, a .diff file but I don't know how to use it. Please help, it worked fine when I installed Ubuntu with wubi.exe. Please help, I don't want to be stuck in single player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally fixed my problem. It seems that Canonical does not like to update their repositories very often. So this is how to install a working version of minetest:

1. Uninstall minetest and minetest-server from Ubuntu Software Center. (go to the Installed tab, minetest is under Games)
2. Press ctrl-alt-T and type into the console "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minetestdevs/stable"
3. If you couldn't uninstall minetest-server from the software center type "sudo apt-get remove minetest-server" or it will not let you install minetest. (of course this whole time you might not have installed minetest-server at all, in which case don't worry about it)
4. Type "sudo apt-get install minetestc55". When the console finishes doing its business, press Super/Start, search for Minetest, and drag the icon into the Launcher.
5. Enjoy.